# Date time conversion in Javascript from format "/Date(1535515200000)/"

Tags: javascript, date, date-conversion

Hi All this is mostly asked question still i didn't find easy and direct way to convert this in to date format.

current format is in

```
"/Date(1535515200000)/"
```

if i executed the below line that will give the needed date format. Is there any direct way to get the date format from "/Date(1535515200000)/" to Wed Aug 29 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

```
new Date(1535515200000)
```

Comment: That looks like a "timestamp"; check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Comment: date am getting from a API is in string format of "/Date(1535515200000)/" i need to convert to  Wed Aug 29 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Comment: I pretty much always use this package when working with javascript datetimes -> https://momentjs.com/ it handles the conversion for that format with no issues and many many many more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = "/Date(1535515200000)/";
var ts = s.substring(s.indexOf('(')+1,s.lastIndexOf(')'));
console.log(new Date(Number(ts)).toISOString());
```

Would print `"2018-08-29T04:00:00.000Z"`

Comment: Much simpler is `new Date(+s.replace(/\D/g,'')).toISOString()`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it from JSON.parse, you can use the reviver parameter and parse it out.

```js
const x = JSON.parse('{"foo": "/Date(1535515200000)/"}', (key, value) =>
  typeof value === 'string' && value.startsWith("/Date(")
    ? new Date(+value.match(/(\d+)/)[0]) // return new date
    : value     // return everything else unchanged
);
console.log(x);
```